# How to create a custom control panel in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

A control panel that has only the functions that I need. How do I create one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen [this](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://blogs.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/window-on-windows/?p=717) method before for Vista. I've reviewed it, and there is no reason it can't work in Windows 7 as well.

It just involves creating a new folder (your custom control panel), then filling it with shortcuts that open the control panels you want via command line (for example, try "control desk.cpl" in a command window, and you'll get the display settings).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want in your custom panel, many of the system utilities are run via snap-ins to the MMC (Microsoft Management Console).

You can author your own custom MMC: start-->run-->'mmc', add snap-ins you want, and then save it for future use.

[Here's some info from MS on authoring your own MMC](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc784817(WS.10).aspx). It's more straight-forward than they make it out to be (as usual :) ).

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Just create a folder and drag &drop the needed functions from the control panel to it...

You could also use the **"Master Control Panel"** aka **"God Mode"**:

```
Create a new folder 
Name it: Master Control Panel.{ED7BA470-8E54-465E-825C-99712043E01C}
```

It's a CLSID (or Windows Class Identifiers) folder and you will find 278 controls in it.

And you could also use directly some other CLSID folders:

```
Right click > New folder > "Name of your choice".GUID
```

- [14 GUID shortcuts that work only in Windows 7 (or later)](http://blogs.zdnet.com/Bott/?p=1615&page=2)
- [25 GUID shortcuts that work in Windows Vista and Windows 7 (or later)](http://blogs.zdnet.com/Bott/?p=1615&page=3)

Additionally, to simplify the creation of these folders: [GodMode Creator](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/godmode-creator-windows-7-vista-released)