# What are these special names, and how do they work?

Tags: windows

On Windows 10, if I create a folder called `whatever.{ED7BA470-8E54-465E-825C-99712043E01C}` it opens a folder with every Control Panel command.

If I enter the location `shell:::{ED7BA470-8E54-465E-825C-99712043E01C}` in the Windows Explorer address bar, I enter the same place. What exactly is this? Are there any other "shortcuts" like this?

I have also found out `{4234d49b-0245-4df3-B780-3893943456e1}` opens an "Applications" folder.

**Note:** I don't mean to create a custom Control Panel, I just want further information about these type of shell "links".

Comment: suggestion:do the topic relevant to others.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a custom control panel in Windows 7](http://superuser.com/questions/120128/how-to-create-a-custom-control-panel-in-windows-7)

Comment: Related: [How do I create the GodMode folder in Windows 7 & Windows 8?](http://superuser.com/questions/91645/how-do-i-create-the-godmode-folder-in-windows-7-windows-8?lq=1), also [Is there a way to enable “god mode” in Windows 8, like you could in Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/questions/495661/is-there-a-way-to-enable-god-mode-in-windows-8-like-you-could-in-windows-7?lq=1)

Comment: I don't know why but I _absolutely love this_.

Answer (score 24):

> [Canonical Names of Control Panel Items](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330741(VS.85).aspx)
>
> As of Windows Vista, Control Panel items included with Windows are
>   given a canonical name that can be used in an API call or a
>   command-line instruction to programmatically launch that item.

The page contains a list of Control Panel Canonical Names.  Examples:

> **Administrative Tools**
>   **Canonical name:** Microsoft.AdministrativeTools
>   **GUID:** {D20EA4E1-3957-11d2-A40B-0C5020524153}
>   **Supported OS:** Windows Vista, Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows 8.1
>   **Module name:** @%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,-22982
>
> **AutoPlay**
>   **Canonical name:** Microsoft.AutoPlay
>   **GUID:** {9C60DE1E-E5FC-40f4-A487-460851A8D915}
>   **Supported OS:** Windows Vista, Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows 8.1
>   **Module name:** @%SystemRoot%\System32\autoplay.dll,-1

The page [KNOWNFOLDERID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762584(VS.85).aspx) contains a list of many "Known Folders" (with GUID's).